# How can I restore an old shopping cart in the user's session for user editing?

Tags: prestashop, cart

I'm developing an e-commerce application with Prestashop 8.1, and I want to implement a feature where users can retrieve and edit their previous shopping carts. I'd like to load their old cart into the session so they can continue shopping or make modifications.

What's the best approach to achieve this? How can I load it into the user's session for editing? Are there any recommended practices or libraries for this scenario?

I'd appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to implement this feature. Thanks in advance!

I already try something like this, but it's does not work :

```
$context->cart = new Cart(40);
$context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$context->cart->id;
```

My cart remains empty after that, but I imagine there must be some things missing, except that I can't find any information about it!